# How to understand by "If you have a change of scenery, you go somewhere different after being in a particular place for a long time."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> If you have a change of scenery, you go somewhere different after being in a particular place for a long time.

Does it mean **you go somewhere different for a long time.** or **you were in a particular place for a long time.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original entry is here. It is a [***phrase (#10)***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/scene) we use to mean something.

It **does not** mean that you go to some different place **for a long time**. But yes, it *does* mean that you **were** at that place for a long time. That is the reason **now** you need to change the surrounding circumstances, routine i.e. the place overall. Maybe, to get rejuvenated or to unwind yourself.

For example, if you are exhausted, stressed, feeling dull in life, a healthcare provider may suggest you to go to some other place. Say a hill station or some beach. So, here, you have a **a change of scenery**.